# Why xgboost show features of feature importance which doen't shown in last tree?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I have data set  with 7 features.
I'm running `xgboost` and plots the last tree:

```
plot_tree(model, num_trees = model.n_estimators-1)
```

- This last tree contains only 2 features.
- To my understanding the last tree (tree number = n_estimators-1) is the tree which is used for prediction (and it's the only one which used for prediction).

I'm plotting the feature importance:

```
plot_importance(model)
```

- This plot has 7 features
- Why do we see the all 7 features and not 2 features ? (I'm asking because the last tree use 2 features and not 7 features).
- To my understanding the feature importance need to be calculated according to the last tree, is it true ? (because this tree is used for the prediction) ?

Answer (score 0):

xgboost used all trees for prediction. (each tree leaf adds some values to the final prediction) Therefor you see 7 features.

I'm reccomending you to watch this video tutorial about how xgboost works:
[XGBoost Part 2 (of 4): Classification](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8b1JEDvenQU&t=1084s)